# SwiftUI: Why does a certain Text tracking value truncate the label?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When using a certain combination of text attributes (smallCaps, tracking, weight) in SwiftUI, the label text gets truncated.

I'm just wondering whether this is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong here.

Please see the following Playground example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct MyView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            // This works as expected.
            Text("Longer Text")
            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).smallCaps())
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .tracking(15)

            // Here, the text gets truncated, even though there is
            // a smaller tracking value set, and there would be enough
            // space to show the complete text.
            Text("Longer Text")
            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).smallCaps())
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .tracking(10)

            // This works as expected.
            Text("Longer Text")
            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).smallCaps())
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .kerning(15)

            // This works as expected.
            Text("Longer Text")
            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).smallCaps())
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .kerning(10)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(MyView())
```

Result:

[image]

I'm using Xcode 11.4, Swift 5.2, and tested in a Playground, on simulators (iOS 13.4), and an iPad (iOS 13.3.1).

Comment: This observed for all values from 1 to 10. Looks like defect. Would you submit feedback to Apple?

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I reported this as FB7650458: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5035788173574144

Comment: I have the same issue here..!